# How to crop character from image using openCV from given Image Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop

### Cropped Only character from Image and remove spaces

I  am trying to remove extra spaces from left and right of character image through opencv .Every image has different dimension .Is there any way to crop or remove extra spaces from left and right only or fetch only character from image.

[image: Input 1]

[image: Input 2]

Comment: [Threshold](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d7/d1b/group__imgproc__misc.html#gae8a4a146d1ca78c626a53577199e9c57) the image (use the `THRESH_BINARY_INV` option), and then find the minimum and maximum x and y values for the remaining non-zero pixels. These four points describe a rectangle, which you can use to create a submatrix of your original image.

Comment: @HansHirse I think create two sub image of image because there two different line segment in one image.

Answer (score 0):

Under the assumption that all your images look like the examples provided you can go with HansHirse's solution.

Segment the image into fore- and background using a global threshold. Then find the extreme coordinates of foreground pixels to define the boundaries of your sub image.

Of course you can do both steps on the fly instead of doing two iterations over your image.

Another solution: Use a blob detector to find the character components and merge their bounding boxes.

Comment: Can you be some more specific about  first approach because I am new to openCv.

Comment: @stock_code  iterate over the image. for all pixels lower than the threshold value remember the lowest and highest x and y coordinates. these coordinates define the sub image you want to crop. maybe you should do a few tutorials if this is unclear